# LINQ OrderBy not sorting as expected on string

Tags: c#, linq, razor

I am using Umbraco CMS to attempt to sort a collection of node's (DynamicNode type), and the LINQ OrderBy statement is not working as one would expect.  I have to be missing something here right?

I have been debugging this as so..

```
DynamicNodeList thingsToDo = Model.Descendants("Tourism-Things-To-Do");
 if (thingsToDo != null && thingsToDo.Count() > 0)
    {
       foreach(dynamic thingToDo in thingsToDo)
        {
           @thingToDo.Name <br />   
        }
        <br />

        foreach(dynamic thingToDo in thingsToDo.OrderBy(x => x.Name, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
           @thingToDo.Name <br />   
        }
    }
```

**Output:**

```
[Unsorted List from First Iteration]
Quality Inn & Suites 
​Days Inn 
Palm Tree Inn 
​Super 8 
​Wyndie Crest Bed & Breakfast

[Should be Alphabetical List from Second Iteration]
​Days Inn 
​Super 8 
​Wyndie Crest Bed & Breakfast 
Palm Tree Inn 
Quality Inn & Suites
```

Could anybody lend me some insight as to why this couldn't be working?  `Name` in this code is just a string.

Comment: Could you try `thingsToDo.OrderBy(x => x.Name.Trim(), StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)` instead? There may be spaces in the names that are not visible when HTML output is rendered.

Comment: You might also gain insight with `<pre> @thingToDo.Name </pre> <br/>`

Comment: I've tried both of the ideas but still no luck .... the output is the same http://puu.sh/kZTe0/7ed123757e.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to break the string apart into a char array and I found the issue to be instances of ZERO-WIDTH space characters at the beginnings of some of my strings.  I scrubbed the Array of these characters and added them back to a list and all works perfectly now.

**CODE:**

```
SortedDictionary<string, int> sd = new SortedDictionary<string, int>();
        foreach(DynamicNode thingToDo in thingsToDo)
        {
            List<char> temp = new List<char>();
            char[] parseWord = thingToDo.Name.ToCharArray();
            var brokenWord = parseWord.Select(x => x == 8203);

            var enumeratorWord = parseWord.GetEnumerator();
            var enumeratorBool = brokenWord.GetEnumerator();
            enumeratorBool.MoveNext();
             while(enumeratorWord.MoveNext())
             {
                 if(!(bool)enumeratorBool.Current)
                 {
                     temp.Add((char)enumeratorWord.Current);
                 }
             }
             var result = string.Join("", temp.ToArray());
             sd.Add(result, thingToDo.Id);   
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that your string could start from the unprintable char. I would recommend you to render the raw string and take a look on it:

```
@Html.Raw(myString)
```

Comment: Not a bad idea,  unfortunately I tried it and the first letter of the string is the true start of the string.

Comment: Have you tried checking the ASCII value of each string?